# How to display the Event Registration Form for public?

Tags: civievent

I am just starting about a week to use CiviCRM & CiviEvents running on Drupal. Managed to create an event and its Online Registration Form.

However, the form appears differently for logged-in and non logged-in users.

**My question:** *How to display the same form for logged-in and non logged-in users?*

What I did so far:

1. I created 2 profiles for the form, "Registration Info" & "Course Type".*
2. On the Event's Online Registration, I included these 2 profiles.
3. If a logged-in user click the Register Now button at the event page the system displays the correct form:

[image]

4. But when public click the button, the system displays this form:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Voldi Sinarta

Comment: what version of CiviCRM are you using ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at permissions. It seems anonymous users are not allowed to access these custom fields.

You can do this with the drupal permission
"CiviCRM: access all custom data "

Or, if you do not want to let anonymous people access all custom data, then you can use the CiviCRM permission system ACL, which lets you configure more fine grained access to custom fields.

More info: http://book.civicrm.org/user/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/